# How can I obtain Wolfram Alpha's "alternative forms" of an expression inside Mathematica?

Tags: expression-manipulation

When I type in Wolfram Alpha, say,

```
cos(a+b)
```

or

```
cos(a+b)^2
```

or (OK this next one can easily be obtained in Mathematica, still, I have run into Bessel function expressions that cannot be simplified by Mathematica, but get a decent "alternative expression" through W|A)

```
D[A^mu BesselK[mu, A r], A]
```

I get several alternative forms of these, but I cannot seem to obtain them simply from **pure** Mathematica (i.e. no W|A integration stuff). Am I missing something or is Wolfram Alpha just smarter in these things? The alternative expressions have helped me quite a lot, so it would be nice to have them in my toolbox without having to access Alpha.

Comment: *Where* do you type those?

Comment: @YvesKlett In W|A I think

Comment: @Öskå yes, indeed, missed that when writing it down :-)

Comment: You can query W|A by entering `=` or `==`?

Comment: So @rubenvb Check `#@Cos[a+b]&/@{TrigToExp,TrigExpand}`

Comment: [guide/WolframAlphaIntegration](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/WolframAlphaIntegration.html)

Comment: I emphasized _pure_ in my question, as in meaning no calls to Wolfram Alpha, which would be cheating. The plan is to either let it work on more complicated expressions (for which W|A times out) or get even more alternative forms.

Comment: Well, without your added interpretation of *pure* this was by no means clear.

Answer (score 10):

You can call Wolfram Alpha directly from the notebook,

```
 Part[#, 2] & /@ 
       WolframAlpha[
        "cos(a+b)^2",{{"AlternativeRepresentations:MathematicalFunctionIdentityData", All},
        "Content"},PodStates ->{"AlternativeRepresentations:MathematicalFunctionIdentityData__More"}]
```

it should give you all the alternate forms.

```
 {HoldForm[Cos[a + b]^2 == Cosh[(a + b)*I]^2], 
  HoldForm[Cos[a + b]^2 == (1/Sec[a + b])^2], 
  HoldForm[Cos[a + b]^2 == Cosh[(-I)*(a + b)]^2], 
  HoldForm[Cos[a + b]^2 == (1/Csc[a + b + Pi/2])^2], 
  HoldForm[Cos[a + b]^2 == ((1/2)*(E^((-I)*(a + b)) + E^((a + b)*I)))^2], 
  HoldForm[Cos[a + b]^2 == (1/Csc[-a - b + Pi/2])^2], 
  HoldForm[Cos[a + b]^2 == (-(I/Csch[(a + b)*I + (I*Pi)/2]))^2], 
  HoldForm[Cos[a + b]^2 == (-(I/Csch[-((a + b)*I) + (I*Pi)/2]))^2]}
```